# How to filter and paginate at the same time in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple data model for a Post:

[image]

I know Firebase can't do `equalTo` and `endAt` on 2 different named properties at the same time.

What's the best way to structure this, so that I can filter on a combination of `locationUid` and `occasionUid` and have an ability to paginate through the results?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?